# Blazor NavigationManager bug

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, blazor

I have a page which has a grid which shows all departments for a company in my system. Users can click on departments and get a department detail page. In the detail page users can see subdepartments of the department and click on them the same way to open a detail page. The subdepartment uses the same URL (department/{departmentGuid}).

For all of our pages we use  to navigate between pages, but since NavLink doesn't reload pages we had to use NavigationManager.NavigateTo with forceLoad set as true for the department pages to get the reload (See code below).

```
<a class="custom-link cursor-pointer" @onclick="@(() => Navigate(@department.DepartmentKey.ToString()))" > 
    @department.DepartmentName
</a>
```

```
public void Navigate(string departmentKey)
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/ems/department/{departmentKey}", true);
}
```

A  bug has been happening in my system where the department detail page doesn't sometimes load. I get no error/exceptions and it's very hard to debug because of that. The only  thing that I think could be causing this is the navigation manager since that is the only big difference between the department detail page and other pages in the system. On top of this, the only time this bug happens is in the production environment (so not in dev/test). If I refresh the page the page loads and the bug disappears for a while.

Could it be that the NavigationManager is causing this (and if so what could possibly fix this) and if not what else could be causing this?

My project is in .net 6 and this is in server side blazor.

Comment: Blazor Navigation Bug?  Probably not, more likely it's a design/coding error.   And then you say "but since NavLink doesn't reload pages we had to use NavigationManager.NavigateTo with forceLoad set as true for the department pages to get the reload".  That's a design issue.  You should not be doing a forced reset of the SPA to solve that problem.   Detect the change in the `DepartmentKey` parameter in `OnParametersSet{Async}` and get the new department data if it has changed.  Show an little more code and I'll provide an answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So if I understand you correctly, I shouldn't reload the page and I should just fetch the new data with the new key through OnParametersSetAsync?

Comment: Yes.  See my answer below for a simple demo using the *Counter* page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick demo to show you how to handle reposting to the same page.  The problem happens because the route maps to the same page component. There just a Parameter change, no `OnInitialized{Async}`.

```cs
@page "/counter"
@page "/counter/{StartCounter:int}"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
<a class="btn btn-dark" href="@_counterUrl">Reset</a>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int StartCounter { get; set; }
    private int _startCounter;
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private string _counterUrl => $"/counter/{_startCounter + 100}";

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (_startCounter != StartCounter)
        {
            currentCount = this.StartCounter;
            _startCounter = this.StartCounter;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```